# java free memory usages

Tags: java, memory, jvm

I'm using java to build a socket server.

I'm logging lots of actions which are happening during the server run,
and beside each log line I'm writing the current free memory in the JVM using the:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()
```

as I can see in my log, I don't have lots of free memory (around 14-15 MB).

I run this socket server on a freeBSD server with root access.

I really want to tune up the memory allocated to my JVM but I don't really know how, and I'm pretty new to freeBSD and linux in general.

Comment: What exactly are you hoping to achieve by "tuning up the memory allocated to your JVM"?

Comment: You can use `-Xms` and `-Xmx` switches to specify how much heap memory to allocate for your program.

Comment: i'm trying to avoid out of memory.. in the future..

Comment: As Jarrod said you might be having some doubts regarding the garbage collection. [Here] is a good whitepaper by *sun* which you should read. [Here]: http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CGkQFjAA&url=http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/memorymanagement-whitepaper-150215.pdf&ei=HSC1T_zSNaOo2wWB_9Qg&usg=AFQjCNFSYblAnBZ2obiu7mm3BpKhIUX07w&sig2=JbAS06JHz54GKlb3w55xUw

Comment: possible duplicate of [Limit jvm process memory on ubuntu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9145769/limit-jvm-process-memory-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You assumption about how memory works ( especially [Garbage Collection](http://www.theserverside.com/tip/Whats-new-in-Java-garbage-collection) ) in Java is flawed.

`Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()`.

[That call only shows *"free"* memory on the JVM heap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3571231/177800), **which is allocated** with the `-Xms` and `-Xmx` command line arguments to `java`. Or in some startup script if you are using an app server.

**Why what you are trying to do is a waste of time**

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9146775/177800) to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9145769/limit-jvm-process-memory-on-ubuntu) why!

The Garbage Collector in Java ( which controls free memory ) isn't tuned to keep as much memory free as possible, it is tuned for a balance of performance and responsiveness. It only frees memory on demand, there is no benefit in having max free memory and lots of downsides to trying to do so.

This causes objects that aren't referenced anymore to hang around "using memory" until the memory they occupy is actually needed. This is actually optimal because prematurely removing them would cause performance degradation of the running code.

Removing them very quickly only when memory needs to be freed is the goal of the Garbage Collector **not** trying to keep as much memory free as possible.

You should **never** have to call `System.gc()` in a correctly implemented Java program.

> Java HotSpot includes three different collectors. The serial
>   collection uses a single thread for GC and is best suited for single
>   processor machines with data sets smaller than 100 Mbytes. The
>   parallel performs minor collections in parallel. It is ideally suited
>   for medium to large datasets running on multi-threaded or
>   multi-processor hardware. The concurrent collector has been optimized
>   to garbage collection pauses short when response time is more
>   important than throughput. This mode does not normally provide any
>   benefit on a single-core machine.

**To avoid OutOfMemoryExceptions**

1. Set `-Xmx` to as large a setting as you can afford on your server. Set `-Xms` to the minimum size of block of memory you think is nominal. Too small is worse than too big.
2. Don't leak references.

Comment: so you're saying that the Garbage Collector will allocate for me more memory (if available) when needed ?

Comment: i'm actually not trying to allocated any memory at all.
what i'm trying to understand is in general, how much memory is my system giving java, or in other words, what is the maximum amount of memory i can use with my java application, and where do i set it

Comment: isn't it some kind of settings in the JVM for how much memory from the system available memory to be used by java applications ?

Comment: Ok but where do i set it? In the java command line? And how do i know what is the maximum size in my server?