# Java HeapDump Analysis: String or StringBuilder, what should be used?

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder, heap-memory

In my application there was a heap dump and surprisingly heap retained by `char[]` was around 700MB, which was strange (at least for me). At the same time `String` had only 150MB.

In my application, I have only used `StringBuilder` (using default `StringBuilder` constructor) and tried to avoid using `String` as we were appending data.

My question here is: Should we always go for `StringBuilder`? And if yes, how can we reduce the heap retained by it?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13360229/4271479

Comment: If you *always* use the default constructor of `StringBuilder`, it will potentially need to keep on allocating larger `char[]` instances internally as you fill them up (requiring roughly twice the space as if the know the eventual size up-front). But probably more importantly, when you build the final `String`, the `char[]` in the `StringBuilder` has to be duplicated.

Comment: You may want to get the finished `String` out of the `StringBuilder`, when you are done appending, and throw the `StringBuilder` away.

Comment: @Andy Turner : We have all String variable declared as final as all of them are local variable.

Comment: I meant final as in "eventual", rather than `final`. A copy of the `char[]` in the `StringBuilder` must be made because it remains mutable, but `String` is immutable (same reason `String.toCharArray()` returns a copy).

Comment: @mastov : I am making every [StringBuilder] null once we are reading String out from it. Even though [StringBuilder] is ready for garbage collection, but it will be only collected whenever JVM wants, this is why we have so much memory occupied by char[].

Comment: @SauravKumarMehta: If that's the reason for the big footprint, then I wouldn't worry about it, since the memory is effectively "made available" (even if it's still in the physical memory) because it *can* be garbage-collected whenever necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, always go for `StringBuilder` when building strings - it's the most efficient, but still convenient, way of concatenating strings.

It sounds like there are lots of `StringBuilder`s hanging around waiting to be garbage collected. However, to reduce heap usage, you can safely *reuse* your `StringBuilder`s even though they are not threadsafe by using one `StringBuilder` per thread via `Threadlocal`:

```
private static final ThreadLocal<StringBuilder> LOCAL_STRING_BUILDER =
    ThreadLocal.withInitial(StringBuilder::new);
```

Example usage:

```
public String logMessage() {
    StringBuilder sb = LOCAL_STRING_BUILDER.get();
    sb.setLength(0); // Only resets the pointer to start. Doesn't affect the backing array
    sb.append("foo=").append(myField); //etc
    return sb.toString();
}
```

You will only ever have at most as many `StringBuilder`s as there are threads, which won't be *that* many (maybe 10's - 100's).

---

FYI `StringBuilder` is used when concatenating strings manually anyway; this line of source:

```
String str3 = str1 + str2;
```

gets compiled as if it were:

```
String str3 = new StringBuilder().append(str1).append(str2).toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you can use StringInterner which takes a StringBuilder to avoid creating objects needlessly.You first populate a recycled StringBuilder with the text and if a String matching that text is in the interner, that String is returned (or a toString() of the StringBuilder is.) The benefit is that you only create objects (and no more than needed) when you see a new String (or at least one not in the array) This can get a 80% to 99% hit rate and reduce memory consumption (and garbage) dramatically when loading many strings of data.

Code:
https://github.com/OpenHFT/Java-Lang/blob/master/lang/src/main/java/net/openhft/lang/pool/StringInterner.java

Comment: At this moment we don't want to add another dependency for 3rd party jar, but it wil be interesting to see what StringInterner does ?

Comment: Have a look into this dicusiion, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26290043/optimizing-java-heap-usage-by-string-using-stringbuffer-stringbuilder-string