# Java maximum memory argument does not appear to work

Tags: java, jar

I have a Jar file that is ran in a server environment on demand, and I would like to limit the amount of memory that it uses so that multiple simultaneous instances can run comfortably. However, after setting the `-Xmx512M` parameter, it appears that Java is still using more memory than that. I am using the following command:

```
 java -Xmx512M -jar Reporter.jar /tmp/REPmKLs8K
```

However I can see that the process is using more than this:

```
Resource:     Virtual Memory Size
Exceeded:     1657 > 400 (MB)
Executable:   /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.91.x86_64/jre/bin/java
Command:      java -Xmx512M -jar Reporter.jar /tmp/REPmKLs8K
```

I'm not sure why this is, and it could potentially be an issue with the memory reporting software (ConfigServer Firewall). Has anyone experienced anything similar?

Comment: Note: virtual memory is virtual, not actual memory.  I suggest you consider only the resident size without shared libraries.

Answer (score 0):

`-Xmx` is the maximum heap size, not the process size.

See: [What does Java option -Xmx stand for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374455/what-does-java-option-xmx-stand-for)

Comment: In that case, is there a way to specify that the whole Java process can only use X amount of memory? Or would this be done externally using a system command?

Comment: @AlexBlundell `ulimit` may work on UNIX systems.  Are you using many many threads?  That value is 3 times your heap limit.

Comment: It's actually just a single (main) thread. I'll give this a try now - thanks

Comment: @AlexBlundell if you reach the `ulimit` it will kill the process. It would be better to find out what memory outside the heap you program is using.

Answer (score 0):

`-Xmx` is used in order to specify the *max heap allocation*, but java needs more memory for JVM, pergem space (Java 7 and below), etc... You can see this [post for memory structure](https://www.yourkit.com/docs/kb/sizes.jsp)

You can use tools like [JVisualVM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html) in order to profile the real memory usage in the JVM.

Comment: Java8 does not have permgen.  He might get a different result using that.

Comment: actually JVisualVM does not show the native memory consumption only the heap, it will just make them more confused.

Answer (score 0):

#### `-Xmx` doesn't control what you think it controls.

It only controls the JVM heap, not everything goes in the JVM heap, and the heap takes up way more native memory that what you specify for management and bookkeeping.

You can't control what you want to control, `-Xmx` only controls the Java Heap, it doesn't control consumption of *native memory* by the JVM, which is consumed completely differently based on implementation. The JVM uses up *native memory* in an entirely different way and it dependant on each JVM implementation and the OS it is running on.

From the following article [Thanks for the Memory ( Understanding How the JVM uses Native Memory on Windows and Linux )](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-nativememory-linux/)

Maintaining the heap and garbage collector use native memory you can't control.

> More native memory is required to maintain the state of the
>   memory-management system maintaining the Java heap. Data structures
>   must be allocated to track free storage and record progress when
>   collecting garbage. The exact size and nature of these data structures
>   varies with implementation, but many are proportional to the size of
>   the heap.

and the JIT compiler uses native memory just like `javac` would

> Bytecode compilation uses native memory (in the same way that a static
>   compiler such as gcc requires memory to run), but both the input (the
>   bytecode) and the output (the executable code) from the JIT must also
>   be stored in native memory. Java applications that contain many
>   JIT-compiled methods use more native memory than smaller applications.

and then you have the classloader(s) which use native memory

> Java applications are composed of classes that define object structure
>   and method logic. They also use classes from the Java runtime class
>   libraries (such as java.lang.String) and may use third-party
>   libraries. These classes need to be stored in memory for as long as
>   they are being used. How classes are stored varies by implementation.

I won't even start quoting the section on Threads.

[Plain and simple the JVM uses more memory than what is supplied in `-Xms` and `-Xmx` and the other command line parameters.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9146775/177800)

The Classloaders, and applications can have more than one, eat up lots of memory that isn't documented easily. The JIT eats up memory, trading space for time, which is a good trade off most of the time.

> Some of the above links **may** refer to older Java versions; Java 8 handles garbage collection and memory allocation differently, but the general rules above apply.