# specifying the amount of ram in eclipse for java projects

Tags: java, eclipse, memory

Where in Eclipse's `Run Configuration` can I specify for the project to run using 3G of my ram?
and how do I do it? (what is the flag or command?)

Comment: You need to use -Xms and -Xmx flags in VM arguments.

Comment: @Nambari thanks for the answer, so it's just -Xms 3g then?

Comment: Yes that is correct. http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Fguide%2Ftools%2Flaunchers%2Farguments.htm

Comment: @BrendanLong: `eclipse.ini` doesn't control memory limits for the programs you launch... it only controls eclipse memory limits.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493913/how-to-set-the-maximum-memory-usage-for-jvm

Comment: Why are you doing this in the first place? 3GB seems to be a lot of ram to test in eclipse.

Comment: yeah, it is this _rescue agent simulation_ code. it really needs at least 3G!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Run Configurations, you go to the Arguments Tab, and then add to the "VM arguments" text field

```
-Xmx3g
```

That will run your program with a max of 3 GBytes of heap

Comment: And make sure you're running on a 64-bit machine with 64-bit Java and 64-bit Eclipse, or you won't get 3GB.

Comment: what is the difference between -Xmx and -Xms?! @David Hofmann

Comment: Xms is the amount of starting heap ram, and Xmx is the maximun it can take. I think that even if you put Xms to 3gb it won't really consume the whole at once. but I am not sure