# Application memory increased by Giga Bytes after calling JNI_CreateJavaVM function

Tags: java, c++, c, java-native-interface

In my C++ application, I need to call some java functions inside a "jar" file through JNI.

Hovever after calling the JNI_CreateJavaVM function, My application memory increased by 3, 4 GBs. I suspect this is due to java VM loading into my application. However, but 3,4 GBs are not acceptable in my context. Can someone please let me know are the any parameters available to reduce the memory requirement.

My Sample Code:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(const int argc, const char** argv)
{
    JNIEnv* p_JNIEnv = NULL;

    JavaVM* jvm;
    JavaVMInitArgs args;
    JavaVMOption options[1];

    args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_2;
    args.nOptions = 1;

    const char* zSystemLibs = "/x01/nptsapp/sujith/ds3api";
    if (!zSystemLibs)
    {
        cout << "SYSTEM_LIBS environment variable not set" << endl;
        return false;
    }

    // ClientAPI, Security and DS3Authenticator class made by us
    char zPath[1024];

    snprintf(zPath, 1024, "-Djava.class.path=%s/clientapi.jar:%s/security-1.2.jar:%s/RSAPasswordEncryptLib.jar:%s", zSystemLibs,
    zSystemLibs, zSystemLibs, zSystemLibs);

    cout << "Class Path=" << zPath << endl;

    options[0].optionString = zPath;
    args.options = options;
    args.ignoreUnrecognized = JNI_FALSE;

    p_JNIEnv = NULL;

    JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&p_JNIEnv, &args);

    if (!p_JNIEnv)
    {
        cout << "JNIEnv Not Created" << endl;
        return false;
    }

    cout << "JNIEnv Created Successful:" << p_JNIEnv << endl;

    cout << getpid() << " Enter:";

    int iValue;
    cin >> iValue;

    return 0;
};
```

Compilation and Running

```
[sujith@nc-110 ~/ds3api]$ ./a.out 
Class Path=-Djava.class.path=/x01/nptsapp/sujith/ds3api/clientapi.jar:/x01/nptsapp/sujith/ds3api/security-1.2.jar:/x01/nptsapp/sujith/ds3api/RSAPasswordEncryptLib.jar:/x01/nptsapp/sujith/ds3api
JNIEnv Created Successful:0x10869e8
21152 Enter:
```

pmap output before the application stops. I added cin for stop the application till I get the pmap output.

```
[sujith@nc-110 ~]$ pmap -d 21152
21152:   ./a.out
Address           Kbytes Mode  Offset           Device    Mapping
0000000000400000       4 r-x-- 0000000000000000 000:00019 a.out
0000000000601000       4 rw--- 0000000000001000 000:00019 a.out
000000000107d000     684 rw--- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
0000000721200000   21504 rw--- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
0000000722700000   62464 rw--- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
0000000726400000  148480 rw--- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
000000072f500000 2229760 rw--- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00000007b7680000   74752 rw--- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00000007bbf80000 1114624 rw--- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
0000003f62000000     128 r-x-- 0000000000000000 068:00002 ld-2.12.so
0000003f6221f000       4 r---- 000000000001f000 068:00002 ld-2.12.so
0000003f62220000       4 rw--- 0000000000020000 068:00002 ld-2.12.so
0000003f62221000       4 rw--- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
0000003f62400000     524 r-x-- 0000000000000000 068:00002 libm-2.12.so
0000003f62483000    2044 ----- 0000000000083000 068:00002 libm-2.12.so
0000003f62682000       4 r---- 0000000000082000 068:00002 libm-2.12.so
0000003f62683000       4 rw--- 0000000000083000 068:00002 libm-2.12.so
0000003f62800000    1628 r-x-- 0000000000000000 068:00002 libc-2.12.so
0000003f62997000    2048 ----- 0000000000197000 068:00002 libc-2.12.so
0000003f62b97000      16 r---- 0000000000197000 068:00002 libc-2.12.so
0000003f62b9b000       4 rw--- 000000000019b000 068:00002 libc-2.12.so
0000003f62b9c000      20 rw--- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
0000003f62c00000       8 r-x-- 0000000000000000 068:00002 libdl-2.12.so
0000003f62c02000    2048 ----- 0000000000002000 068:00002 libdl-2.12.so
0000003f62e02000       4 r---- 0000000000002000 068:00002 libdl-2.12.so
0000003f62e03000       4 rw--- 0000000000003000 068:00002 libdl-2.12.so
0000003f63000000      92 r-x-- 0000000000000000 068:00002 libpthread-2.12.so
0000003f63017000    2044 ----- 0000000000017000 068:00002 libpthread-2.12.so
0000003f63216000       4 r---- 0000000000016000 068:00002 libpthread-2.12.so
0000003f63217000       4 rw--- 0000000000017000 068:00002 libpthread-2.12.so
0000003f63218000      16 rw--- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
0000003f63800000      28 r-x-- 0000000000000000 068:00002 librt-2.12.so
0000003f63807000    2044 ----- 0000000000007000 068:00002 librt-2.12.so
0000003f63a06000       4 r---- 0000000000006000 068:00002 librt-2.12.so
0000003f63a07000       4 rw--- 0000000000007000 068:00002 librt-2.12.so
0000003f6a800000      88 r-x-- 0000000000000000 068:00002 libgcc_s-4.4.6-20110824.so.1
0000003f6a816000    2044 ----- 0000000000016000 068:00002 libgcc_s-4.4.6-20110824.so.1
0000003f6aa15000       4 rw--- 0000000000015000 068:00002 libgcc_s-4.4.6-20110824.so.1
0000003f6e000000     928 r-x-- 0000000000000000 068:00002 libstdc++.so.6.0.13
0000003f6e0e8000    2048 ----- 00000000000e8000 068:00002 libstdc++.so.6.0.13
0000003f6e2e8000      28 r---- 00000000000e8000 068:00002 libstdc++.so.6.0.13
0000003f6e2ef000       8 rw--- 00000000000ef000 068:00002 libstdc++.so.6.0.13
0000003f6e2f1000      84 rw--- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00007f1f10000000     132 rw--- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00007f1f10021000   65404 ----- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00007f1f14000000     132 rw--- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00007f1f14021000   65404 ----- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00007f1f18000000     132 rw--- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00007f1f18021000   65404 ----- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00007f1f1c000000     132 rw--- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00007f1f1c021000   65404 ----- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00007f1f20000000     132 rw--- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00007f1f20021000   65404 ----- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00007f1f2616f000   96836 r---- 0000000000000000 068:00002 locale-archive
00007f1f2c000000     132 rw--- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00007f1f2c021000   65404 ----- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00007f1f30000000     132 rw--- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00007f1f30021000   65404 ----- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00007f1f34000000     132 rw--- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00007f1f34021000   65404 ----- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00007f1f39090000  114112 rw--- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00007f1f40000000     132 rw--- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00007f1f40021000   65404 ----- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00007f1f470ae000       4 rw--- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00007f1f470af000       4 ----- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00007f1f470b0000    1024 rw--- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00007f1f471b0000      12 ----- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00007f1f471b3000    1016 rw--- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00007f1f472b1000      12 ----- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00007f1f472b4000    1016 rw--- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00007f1f473b2000      12 ----- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00007f1f473b5000    1016 rw--- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00007f1f474b3000      12 ----- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00007f1f474b6000    1016 rw--- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00007f1f475b4000      12 ----- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00007f1f475b7000    1016 rw--- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00007f1f476b5000      12 ----- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00007f1f476b8000    1016 rw--- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00007f1f477b6000       4 ----- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00007f1f477b7000    8484 rw--- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00007f1f48000000     132 rw--- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00007f1f48021000   65404 ----- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00007f1f4c08d000    2488 rw--- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00007f1f4c2fb000    1788 r--s- 00000000039e5000 068:00002 rt.jar
00007f1f4c4ba000    8408 rw--- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00007f1f4ccf0000       4 ----- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00007f1f4ccf1000    1024 rw--- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00007f1f4cdf1000       4 ----- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00007f1f4cdf2000    1068 rw--- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00007f1f4cefd000     120 rw--- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00007f1f4cf1b000     292 rw--- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00007f1f4cf64000    4356 rw--- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00007f1f4d3a5000      44 rw--- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00007f1f4d3b0000     120 rw--- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00007f1f4d3ce000     292 rw--- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00007f1f4d417000    4352 rw--- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00007f1f4d857000     148 rw--- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00007f1f4d87c000    2176 rw--- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00007f1f4da9c000      44 rw--- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00007f1f4daa7000     728 rw--- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00007f1f4db5d000    2496 rwx-- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00007f1f4ddcd000   46656 rw--- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00007f1f50b5d000     104 r-x-- 0000000000000000 068:00002 libzip.so
00007f1f50b77000    2048 ----- 000000000001a000 068:00002 libzip.so
00007f1f50d77000       4 rw--- 000000000001a000 068:00002 libzip.so
00007f1f50d78000      44 r-x-- 0000000000000000 068:00002 libnss_ldap.so.2
00007f1f50d83000    2044 ----- 000000000000b000 068:00002 libnss_ldap.so.2
00007f1f50f82000       4 rw--- 000000000000a000 068:00002 libnss_ldap.so.2
00007f1f50f83000      48 r-x-- 0000000000000000 068:00002 libnss_files-2.12.so
00007f1f50f8f000    2048 ----- 000000000000c000 068:00002 libnss_files-2.12.so
00007f1f5118f000       4 r---- 000000000000c000 068:00002 libnss_files-2.12.so
00007f1f51190000       4 rw--- 000000000000d000 068:00002 libnss_files-2.12.so
00007f1f511a8000     164 r-x-- 0000000000000000 068:00002 libjava.so
00007f1f511d1000    2048 ----- 0000000000029000 068:00002 libjava.so
00007f1f513d1000       8 rw--- 0000000000029000 068:00002 libjava.so
00007f1f513d3000      52 r-x-- 0000000000000000 068:00002 libverify.so
00007f1f513e0000    2044 ----- 000000000000d000 068:00002 libverify.so
00007f1f515df000       8 rw--- 000000000000c000 068:00002 libverify.so
00007f1f515e1000      28 rw--- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00007f1f515f4000      32 rw-s- 0000000000000000 068:00002 21152
00007f1f515fc000       4 rw--- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00007f1f515fd000       4 r---- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00007f1f515fe000       4 rw--- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00007f1f515ff000   11712 r-x-- 0000000000000000 068:00002 libjvm.so
00007f1f5216f000    2044 ----- 0000000000b70000 068:00002 libjvm.so
00007f1f5236e000     788 rw--- 0000000000b6f000 068:00002 libjvm.so
00007f1f52433000     260 rw--- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00007fffac53e000      12 ----- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
00007fffac542000    1008 rw--- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ stack ]
00007fffac7ff000       4 r-x-- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
ffffffffff600000       4 r-x-- 0000000000000000 000:00000   [ anon ]
mapped: 4655428K    writeable/private: 3860404K    shared: 1820K
[sujith@nc-110 ~]$
```

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious first thing to try is, I guess, to use the VM's command line option(s) to set the max memory usage.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493913/how-to-set-the-maximum-memory-usage-for-jvm) has a lot discussion (it's not easy to 100% limit the VM's memory usage) but the simplest thing to try is to limit the heap. Add `-Xmx100M` to set the heap maximum to 100 MB.