# limit amount of RAM the JVM will be allocated

Tags: java, tws

I am running TWS from Interactive Brokers in Parallels on a Mac.  When I use the cloud-based link or the stand-alone application, TWS takes up 99% of available CPU.  Is there a way that I can limit amount of RAM the JVM will be allocated?

I have 4gig of memory allocated to the Parallels VM.  TWS is taking up about 433K of memory.

I added -Xmx300M -Xms300M to the command line for starting TWS, but this did nothing. When I start up, it is still consuming 99% of CPU and has 400K of memory allocated

Comment: what is the conection between CPU consumption and RAM allocation??

Comment: @sharonbn one possiblity is having a GC running continuosly because heap is full, but it would eventually get an `OutOfMemoryException`

Comment: Does it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493913/how-to-set-the-maximum-memory-usage-for-jvm answer your question?

Comment: If the CPU time is going in garbage collection, you want to *increase* the RAM, not decrease it.

Comment: Thanks.  Can I add these "-Xms<memory> -Xmx<memory>"  arguments to the short cut?  Do I want to limit memory or CPU usage?

Comment: You can't limit CPU usage, and I've already addressed the other part of that. What you can add to the shortcut depends on the nature of the shortcut.

Comment: I added -Xmx300M -Xms300M to the command line for starting TWS, but this did nothing.  When I start up, it is still consuming 99% of CPU and has 400K of memory allocated.

Comment: So GC isn't the problem then, or RAM. So your question is now null. Start again. Find out what thread is running and what it's doing.

Comment: Setting the maximum heap of a JVM doesn't limit all memory usage, there is the threads, the shared libraries, the GUI component, socket buffers etc.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem to be with Parallels.  I was using Parallels 8.  When I used TWS on a stand-alone Windows machine, the CPU usage never exceeded 50%.

I created a new VM with Parallels 8, and the CPU usage was still 99%.

I upgraded to Parallels 11 and created a new VM and installed TWS.  Now it takes less than 10%.

Comment: TWS takes way more memory than 300M.  My guess is you reinstalled TWS and used the default cmd line from the install which includes ` -Xmx768M -XX:MaxPermSize=128M`, so now you have enough memory.