# Limit Jython Interpreter memory usage

Tags: java, python, jython, jython-2.7

**Is there anyway to limit the amount of memory that the Jython interpreter uses?**

I've looked into trying to limit the memory usage from inside of the python script but I can't find a cross platform method of doing that.

```
interpreter = new PythonInterpreter();
interpreter.setMemoryLimit(1024) //something like this for example
interpreter.execfile("mycode.py");
```

Comment: I think this can only be done from the command line: `-Xmx<memory>` will set your maximum memory for a JVM instance.  C.f. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493913/how-to-set-the-maximum-memory-usage-for-jvm

Comment: @markspace Yeah that will limit the entire JVM instance like you said. That's a no can do for my application.

Comment: Does *any* Java library allow you to do this thing?

Comment: @DavidCharles Not that I know of. Do you have any recommendations?