# How to set the maximum amount of memory the JVM process will try to allocate?

Tags: java, memory, containers, limit

I'm trying to set the maximum amount of bytes that the JVM process will try to allocate. Im **not talking about the heap** but total amount of memory on OS level.
I've looked hard but haven't found any solutions, which I find hard to believe. Even with Java 10 which should be able to stay within container memory boundaries.

This question has been asked before some 9 years ago (See: [How to set the maximum memory usage for JVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493913/how-to-set-the-maximum-memory-usage-for-jvm)) but the **answer is incorrect**.

The `Runtime` object contains a `maxMemory()` method which is **incorrectly** documented as follows:

> Returns the maximum amount of memory that the Java virtual machine will attempt to use.

The `maxMemory()` method returns the maximum amount of Heap and not the total amount of memory the JVM process can claim.

**Question**: Is it really true that the JVM cannot manage a hard limit on its own memory use?

Answer (score 0):

There probably is no strict limit that can be easily set, e.g. Java thread stacks, compiled code and NIO buffers are allocated off-heap. Even if we sum up `-Xmx`, `-Xss`, `-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize` and other options there is always possibility that custom native code interacting through Java Native Interface will manage it's own memory.