# Elusive Java memory leak

Tags: java, memory-leaks, lwjgl

I have Java application that is based on LWJGL. I am rendering terrain via 9 vertex buffers arranged in a 3 x 3 grid. When the camera moves past a certain boundary, the 9 buffers are either updated or replaced with a new set of terrain. This all works fine except that when a new block of terrain is added the 9 element array, I get a memory increase of about 5MB. This alone is expected. What is not expected is that the 5MB of memory the previous terrain chunk was occupying is not getting cleaned up.

I have exhausted my Google-fu so I'm hoping someone can give me some help. I have VisualVM installed and running. What I don't understand is that Windows shows my application using say 200MB after a lot of terrain loading and unloading. But the VisualVM heap dump shows only 12MB.

The game loop for loading a terrain is not running in a seprerate thread from "main". Can anyone point me in the right direction? I'd paste some code, but its so large I'm not sure which bit to paste.

```
while(Game.running) {

        time = Sys.getTime();
        dt = (double)((time - lastTime))/1000.0;
        lastTime = time;

        GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        input.pollInput(cam, dt);
        cam.update(terrain.getTerrainHeight());
        sun.render();
        terrain.updateNew(cam.getPosition());
        terrain.render();
        frameRendering();
        //testTriangle();
        Display.update();
    }
```

There is the main loop. The problem seems to be occuring in the terrain.updateNew() function.

Which is here:

```
public void updateNew(Vector3f playerPos)
{
    _playerPos.x = playerPos.x;
    _playerPos.y = playerPos.y;
    _playerPos.z = playerPos.z;
    int width = TerrainChunk.CHUNK_WIDTH;
    _westernBounds = _chunks[4].getOrigin().x + 0;
    _easternBounds = _chunks[4].getOrigin().x + width - 0;
    _northernBounds = _chunks[4].getOrigin().z + 0;
    _southernBounds = _chunks[4].getOrigin().z + width - 0;

    if(_playerPos.x < _westernBounds && !_needUpdate)
    {
        _needUpdate = true;
        _inWestBounds = true;
    }

    if(_playerPos.x > _easternBounds && !_needUpdate)
    {
        _needUpdate = true;
        _inEastBounds = true;
    }

    if(_playerPos.z < _northernBounds && !_needUpdate)
    {
        _needUpdate = true;
        _inNorthBounds = true;
    }

    if(_playerPos.z > _southernBounds && !_needUpdate)
    {
        _needUpdate = true;
        _inSouthBounds = true;
    }

    if(_needUpdate)
    {
        long key = 0;
        long key1 = 0;
        long key2 = 0;
        int[] coords = new int[2];
        HashMap<Integer, Long> needed = new HashMap<Integer, Long>();

        coords = calculateChunkCoords(0);
        key1 = coords[0];
        key2 = coords[1];
        key = key1 << 32 | key2;
        needed.put(0, key);

        coords = calculateChunkCoords(1);
        key1 = coords[0];
        key2 = coords[1];
        key = key1 << 32 | key2;
        needed.put(1, key);

        coords = calculateChunkCoords(2);
        key1 = coords[0];
        key2 = coords[1];
        key = key1 << 32 | key2;
        needed.put(2, key);

        coords = calculateChunkCoords(3);
        key1 = coords[0];
        key2 = coords[1];
        key = key1 << 32 | key2;
        needed.put(3, key);

        coords = calculateChunkCoords(4);
        key1 = coords[0];
        key2 = coords[1];
        key = key1 << 32 | key2;
        needed.put(4, key);

        coords = calculateChunkCoords(5);
        key1 = coords[0];
        key2 = coords[1];
        key = key1 << 32 | key2;
        needed.put(5, key);

        coords = calculateChunkCoords(6);
        key1 = coords[0];
        key2 = coords[1];
        key = key1 << 32 | key2;
        needed.put(6, key);

        coords = calculateChunkCoords(7);
        key1 = coords[0];
        key2 = coords[1];
        key = key1 << 32 | key2;
        needed.put(7, key);

        coords = calculateChunkCoords(8);
        key1 = coords[0];
        key2 = coords[1];
        key = key1 << 32 | key2;
        needed.put(8, key);

        // copy the chunks we have into a searchable has map
        HashMap<Long, TerrainChunk> have = new HashMap<Long, TerrainChunk>();
        key1 = _chunks[0]._origin[0];
        key2 = _chunks[0]._origin[1];
        key = key1 << 32 | key2;
        have.put(key, new TerrainChunk(_chunks[0], _chunks[0]._color));
        key1 = _chunks[1]._origin[0];
        key2 = _chunks[1]._origin[1];
        key = key1 << 32 | key2;
        have.put(key, new TerrainChunk(_chunks[1], _chunks[1]._color));
        key1 = _chunks[2]._origin[0];
        key2 = _chunks[2]._origin[1];
        key = key1 << 32 | key2;
        have.put(key, new TerrainChunk(_chunks[2], _chunks[2]._color));
        key1 = _chunks[3]._origin[0];
        key2 = _chunks[3]._origin[1];
        key = key1 << 32 | key2;
        have.put(key, new TerrainChunk(_chunks[3], _chunks[3]._color));
        key1 = _chunks[4]._origin[0];
        key2 = _chunks[4]._origin[1];
        key = key1 << 32 | key2;
        have.put(key, new TerrainChunk(_chunks[4], _chunks[4]._color));
        key1 = _chunks[5]._origin[0];
        key2 = _chunks[5]._origin[1];
        key = key1 << 32 | key2;
        have.put(key, new TerrainChunk(_chunks[5], _chunks[5]._color));
        key1 = _chunks[6]._origin[0];
        key2 = _chunks[6]._origin[1];
        key = key1 << 32 | key2;
        have.put(key, new TerrainChunk(_chunks[6], _chunks[6]._color));
        key1 = _chunks[7]._origin[0];
        key2 = _chunks[7]._origin[1];
        key = key1 << 32 | key2;
        have.put(key, new TerrainChunk(_chunks[7], _chunks[7]._color));
        key1 = _chunks[8]._origin[0];
        key2 = _chunks[8]._origin[1];
        key = key1 << 32 | key2;
        have.put(key, new TerrainChunk(_chunks[8], _chunks[8]._color));


        Set<Entry<Integer, Long>> set = needed.entrySet();
        Iterator<Entry<Integer, Long>> i = set.iterator();
        // Garbage cleanup?
        while(i.hasNext())
        {
            Map.Entry<Integer, Long> me = i.next();
            if(have.containsKey(me.getValue()))
            {
                _chunks[me.getKey()] = null;
                _chunks[me.getKey()] = new TerrainChunk(have.get(me.getValue()), getColor(me.getKey()));
            } else {
                _chunks[me.getKey()].destroy();
                _chunks[me.getKey()] = null;
                _chunks[me.getKey()] = new TerrainChunk(calculateChunkCoords(me.getKey()), getColor(me.getKey()), this);
            }
        }
        _needUpdate = false;
        have.clear();
        needed.clear();
        have = null;
        needed = null;
    }
}
```

Here is the function that creates the vertex buffers:

```
private boolean createVertexBuffer()
{
    _vboVertexAttribues = ARBVertexBufferObject.glGenBuffersARB();
    _vboVertexIndices = ARBVertexBufferObject.glGenBuffersARB();
    //_vboVertexTexture = ARBVertexBufferObject.glGenBuffersARB();

    ARBVertexBufferObject.glBindBufferARB(
            ARBVertexBufferObject.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, 
            _vboVertexAttribues
    );

    ARBVertexBufferObject.glBufferDataARB(
            ARBVertexBufferObject.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, 
            (VERTEX_SIZE * VERTEX_COUNT), 
            ARBVertexBufferObject.GL_STATIC_DRAW_ARB
    );

    ByteBuffer vertextPositionAttributes = ARBVertexBufferObject.glMapBufferARB(
            ARBVertexBufferObject.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, 
            ARBVertexBufferObject.GL_WRITE_ONLY_ARB, 
            (VERTEX_SIZE * VERTEX_COUNT),
            null
    );

    for(int i = 0; i < VERTEX_COUNT; i++)
    {
        vertextPositionAttributes.putDouble(_vPos[i].x);
        vertextPositionAttributes.putDouble(_vPos[i].y);
        vertextPositionAttributes.putDouble(_vPos[i].z);
        vertextPositionAttributes.putDouble(_vNorm[i].x);
        vertextPositionAttributes.putDouble(_vNorm[i].y);
        vertextPositionAttributes.putDouble(_vNorm[i].z);
        vertextPositionAttributes.putFloat(_color.x);
        vertextPositionAttributes.putFloat(_color.y);
        vertextPositionAttributes.putFloat(_color.z);
        vertextPositionAttributes.putFloat(1.0f);
    }


    vertextPositionAttributes.flip();

    ARBVertexBufferObject.glUnmapBufferARB(ARBVertexBufferObject.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB);
    ARBVertexBufferObject.glBindBufferARB(ARBVertexBufferObject.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, 0);    

    vertextPositionAttributes.clear();
    vertextPositionAttributes = null;
    // TEXTURE COORDS
    /*ARBVertexBufferObject.glBindBufferARB(
            ARBVertexBufferObject.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB,
            _vboVertexTexture
            );

    ARBVertexBufferObject.glBufferDataARB(
            ARBVertexBufferObject.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB,
            (TEXTURE_SIZE * VERTEX_COUNT),
            ARBVertexBufferObject.GL_STATIC_DRAW_ARB
        );

    ByteBuffer vertexTextureCoords = ARBVertexBufferObject.glMapBufferARB(
            ARBVertexBufferObject.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB,
            ARBVertexBufferObject.GL_WRITE_ONLY_ARB,
            (TEXTURE_SIZE * VERTEX_COUNT),
            null
        );

    for(int i = 0; i < VERTEX_COUNT; i++)
    {
        vertexTextureCoords.putFloat(_vTex[i].x);
        vertexTextureCoords.putFloat(_vTex[i].y);
    }
    vertexTextureCoords.flip();

    ARBVertexBufferObject.glUnmapBufferARB(ARBVertexBufferObject.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB);
    ARBVertexBufferObject.glBindBufferARB(ARBVertexBufferObject.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, 0);*/


    ARBVertexBufferObject.glBindBufferARB(
            ARBVertexBufferObject.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB,
            _vboVertexIndices
    );

    ARBVertexBufferObject.glBufferDataARB(
            ARBVertexBufferObject.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB,
            (INDEX_SIZE * INDEX_COUNT),
            ARBVertexBufferObject.GL_STATIC_DRAW_ARB
    );

    ByteBuffer vertexIndices = ARBVertexBufferObject.glMapBufferARB(
            ARBVertexBufferObject.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB,
            ARBVertexBufferObject.GL_WRITE_ONLY_ARB,
            (INDEX_SIZE * INDEX_COUNT),
            null
    );

    for(int i = 0; i < _nIndices.length; i++)
    {
        vertexIndices.putInt(_nIndices[i]);
    }

    vertexIndices.flip();

    ARBVertexBufferObject.glUnmapBufferARB(ARBVertexBufferObject.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB);
    ARBVertexBufferObject.glBindBufferARB(ARBVertexBufferObject.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, 0);

    // Cleanup our crap
    _fXs = null;
    _fYs = null;
    _fZs = null;
    _vPos = null;
    _vNorm = null;
    _color = null;
    _nIndices = null;
    _vTex = null;
    vertexIndices.clear();
    vertexIndices = null;
    return true;
}
```

And here is the render function: 
    public void render()
    {

```
    GL11.glEnableClientState(GL11.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    GL11.glEnableClientState(GL11.GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    GL11.glEnableClientState(GL11.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    ARBVertexBufferObject.glBindBufferARB(
            ARBVertexBufferObject.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB,
            _vboVertexAttribues
    );

    ARBVertexBufferObject.glBindBufferARB(
            ARBVertexBufferObject.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB,
            _vboVertexIndices
    );

    GL11.glVertexPointer(
            3,
            GL11.GL_DOUBLE,
            VERTEX_SIZE,
            0
    );

    GL11.glNormalPointer(
            GL11.GL_DOUBLE,
            VERTEX_SIZE,
            NORMAL_SIZE
    );

    GL11.glColorPointer(
            4, 
            GL11.GL_FLOAT, 
            VERTEX_SIZE, 
            POSITION_SIZE + NORMAL_SIZE
    );


    GL11.glDrawElements(
            GL11.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP,
            INDEX_COUNT,
            GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_INT,
            0
    );

    ARBVertexBufferObject.glBindBufferARB(
            ARBVertexBufferObject.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB,
            0
    );

    ARBVertexBufferObject.glBindBufferARB(
            ARBVertexBufferObject.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB,
            0
    );

    GL11.glDisableClientState(GL11.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    GL11.glDisableClientState(GL11.GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    GL11.glDisableClientState(GL11.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help or advise.

Comment: Is your application actually running out of memory? The JVM doesn't release memory very often and the GC only runs when it really needs to. Have you tried asking the JVM to actually perform a GC to see what happens? Have you tried using a lower -Xmx value to see whether the JVM is actually unable to free memory?

Comment: Why do you expect the 5Mb increase? Each buffer is approximately 5mb/9??

Comment: I have run the garbage collector manually, which does change the heap size in virtualVM but not the OS memory allocation.

Comment: The data used to calculate the vertex buffers is fairly large. Lots of Vector3f's

Comment: Where are the large vertex buffer in your code? Where is it originally created? is it inside `calculateChunkCoords()`. If yes post the code too.

Comment: I added two more code blocks to the original question. Thanks for all the help so far!

Answer (score 4):

I think it could be an artifact of the way Java VMs allocate memory from the OS, particularly their tendency not to release pages even if the heap shrinks, but to keep it in case the heap has to grow again.

But as far as memory leakage in your code is concerned, all that matters is what VisualVM says your heap size is. If that's stable, there's no leakage there.

You should also take into account that the Java VM itself uses a lot of native libraries and other things that consume physical or virtual memory, which gives a roughly constant overhead for each Java process.

([This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561245/virtual-memory-usage-from-java-under-linux-too-much-memory-used) might help too.)

Answer (score 2):

The leaks may be happening inside the underlying native libraries. It seems LWJGL is binded to native C libraries (OpenGL, OpenAL, etc..), and I suspect that there are temporary memory buffers used for display which are never released. This will explain why VisualVM shows only 12 MB (the objects he is taking care of), while Windows shows 200 MB (the data created both by the JVM, still inside the GC and the data used in the C libraries).

Are you sure you are correctly using the Framework?

EDIT:

I may be mistaken because I am not familiar with this specific library, but 
indeed **you are using native library for memory allocations\operations**.

Seems you are doing all fine, but I noticed

`ARBBufferObject.glGenBuffersARB`

which allocate your buffer. This method **is wrapping a C native**, so until you call

`ARBBufferObject.glDeleteBuffersARB`

or terminate this buffer will persist in memory. You should determine the life cycle of the data created by `createVertexBuffer()`, how many time you call it, and delete the buffers when neither both you and the GPU has finished with this.

Again I don't know this side of OpenGl so somebody who can is more probable to help you.
You notice that the [API of ARBBufferObject](http://lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/opengl/ARBBufferObject.html) is the same as the one discussed in [C++ Wiki](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_vbo.html)

Comment: I think I am. However, im new to LWJGL so I wont rule out the possiblility that I am not. I've pasted the vertex creation function in the original post.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple: the buffer your putting the vertices in "vertextPositionAttributes" is most probably a direct buffer what means that it exists out of the GC controlled heap, and is invisilble to the JVisualVM.