# How can I find Java heap size and memory used (Linux)?

Tags: java, linux, performance, memory, heap-memory

How can I check heap size (and used memory) of a Java application on Linux through the command line?

I have tried through jmap. But it gives information about internal memory areas, like Eden, PermGen, etc., which is not useful to me.

I am looking for something like:

- Maximum Memory: 1 GB
- Minimum Memory: 256 MB
- Heap Memory: 700 MB
- Used Memory: 460 MB

That's all. I know that I can see this in [JConsole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JConsole), etc., but I need to do it via the command-line (I can't enable [JMX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Management_Extensions), etc.)

Answer (score 203):

Each Java process has a `pid`, which you first need to find with the `jps` command.

Once you have the pid, you can use `jstat -gc [insert-pid-here]` to find statistics of the behavior of the garbage collected heap.

- `jstat -gccapacity [insert-pid-here]` will present information about memory pool generation and space capabilities.
- `jstat -gcutil [insert-pid-here]` will present the utilization of each generation as a percentage of its capacity. Useful to get an at a glance view of usage.

See [jstat docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/jstat.html) on Oracle's site.

Comment: Is there a recommendation which options of `jstat` one should use in order to verify just the overall memory usage of a JVM? Let's say you start the JVM with `Xms=4g` and `Xmx=4g` and you want to see, how much memory of that is already used?

Comment: "jstat -gcutil <pid> 250 N" was very useful to take N samples with 250ms intervals and display the output as percentages for the corresponding spaces. Thanks.

Comment: Worth noting quote from `jstat` Oracle Java 8 manual [page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/jstat.html): `This command is experimental and unsupported`.

Comment: `awk 'print {$3+$4+$6+$8}'` can print summarized usage on Java 8's jstat columns

Comment: Had trouble with the other answers, but a basic `ps -ef | grep java` showed me the vm args, which in my case included the -Xmx value, which was all I needed.

Comment: @cybersoft should be `awk '{print $3+$4+$6+$8}'`

Comment: and also, it should be `awk '{print $3+$9}'` aka NGC + OGC, if we don't consider perm space.

Comment: or `awk 'NR>1 {print $3+$4+$6+$8}'` to skip first line with column titles

Comment: @xdhmoore FYI `ps` reports usage of the entire process, not just the java heap.

Answer (score 134):

This command shows the configured heap sizes in bytes.

```
java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep HeapSize
```

It works on Amazon AMI on EC2 as well.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which specifically asks how to check heap usage of  a process.  The command here lists JVM defaults across all processes.

Comment: Yet, it is a very helpful answer for me coming to this page via google search on how to find the global heap size.

Comment: @jumping_monkey not indirect, incorrect. If what you're saying is true, the answer should be edited or you should feel free to add a new answer.

Comment: The initial question's title is ambiguous enough that this should remain a listed answer. Furthermore, it is the most findable answer on google to answer the configuration question.

Answer (score 79):

[jvmtop](https://github.com/patric-r/jvmtop) is a command-line tool which provides a live-view at several metrics, including heap.

#### Example output of the VM overview mode:

```
 JvmTop 0.3 alpha (expect bugs)  amd64  8 cpus, Linux 2.6.32-27, load avg 0.12
 http://code.google.com/p/jvmtop

  PID MAIN-CLASS      HPCUR HPMAX NHCUR NHMAX    CPU     GC    VM USERNAME   #T DL
 3370 rapperSimpleApp  165m  455m  109m  176m  0.12%  0.00% S6U37 web        21
11272 ver.resin.Resin [ERROR: Could not attach to VM]
27338 WatchdogManager   11m   28m   23m  130m  0.00%  0.00% S6U37 web        31
19187 m.jvmtop.JvmTop   20m 3544m   13m  130m  0.93%  0.47% S6U37 web        20
16733 artup.Bootstrap  159m  455m  166m  304m  0.12%  0.00% S6U37 web        46
```

Comment: It is indeed a great tool, kind of htop but with metrics from jstat. Thanks for suggestion, @MRalwasser .

Comment: only works until java 8 because of tools.jar dependency

Answer (score 63):

Try this it worked in Ubuntu and RedHat:

```
java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep -iE 'HeapSize|PermSize|ThreadStackSize'
```

For Windows:

```
java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | findstr /i "HeapSize PermSize ThreadStackSize"
```

For Mac

```
java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep -iE 'heapsize|permsize|threadstacksize'
```

The output of all this commands resembles the output below:

```
uintx InitialHeapSize                          := 20655360        {product}
uintx MaxHeapSize                              := 331350016       {product}
uintx PermSize                                  = 21757952        {pd product}
uintx MaxPermSize                               = 85983232        {pd product}
intx ThreadStackSize                           = 1024            {pd product}
java version "1.7.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_05-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.1-b03, mixed mode)
```

To find the size in MB, divide the value with (1024*1024).

Comment: How to find the memory usage separated by heap, permsize,... of specific java process by pid ?

Comment: @GaryGauh This is the default heap size. To find usage of running application you should  do it within code or you can use jconsole.  This is what I know there should also be many other ways.

Comment: Use `jstat -gc <vmid>` for running applications.

Answer (score 42):

Without using JMX, which is what most tools use, all you can do is use

```
jps -lvm
```

and infer that the settings will be from the command line options.

You can't get dynamic information without JMX by default but you could write your own service to do this.

BTW: I prefer to use VisualVM rather than JConsole.

Answer (score 33):

From **Java8 and above**, you may use below command:

jcmd `JAVA_PROCESS_ID` GC.heap_info

You may refer to sum of, total and used memory from the output.

```
Sample Command And Output: jcmd 9758 GC.heap_info

PSYoungGen  total 1579520K, used 487543K [0x0000000751d80000, 0x00000007c0000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 1354240K, 36% used [0x0000000751d80000,0x000000076f99dc40,0x00000007a4800000)
  from space 225280K, 0% used [0x00000007b2400000,0x00000007b2400000,0x00000007c0000000)
  to   space 225280K, 0% used [0x00000007a4800000,0x00000007a4800000,0x00000007b2400000)
ParOldGen       total 3610112K, used 0K [0x0000000675800000, 0x0000000751d80000, 0x0000000751d80000)
  object space 3610112K, 0% used [0x0000000675800000,0x0000000675800000,0x0000000751d80000)
Metaspace       used 16292K, capacity 16582K, committed 16896K, reserved 1064960K
  class space    used 1823K, capacity 1936K, committed 2048K, reserved 1048576K
```

For more details on jcmd command, visit link [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr006.html)

Comment: You need to correct your comment. GC.heap_info is available in Java 9 and above. It's not available in the Java 8. See another thread here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41891127/jcmd-where-can-i-find-complementary-information

Comment: @PavelMolchanov I am able to use the command in jdk1.8.0_172. /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_172.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/jcmd 98270 GC.heap_info. 
Please if you may, Add the info to referred thread as well as I don't have enough reputation as of now to add a comment there.

Comment: Do you use Mac? Do you use Oracle JDK? I don't know how it can be available in your jdk1.8.0_172, Oracle documented this feature only in Java 9 and up: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/jcmd.htm. It's not in the Oracle JDK documentation for Java 8. It's not mentioned in the link that you gave at the bottom: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr006.html

Comment: One more question. Please check JDK version that is running process 98270 in your example. jcmd gets available commands from JVM of the process (in your case 98270). If process 98270 process is executed with different JDK (JDK 9 or above), you will see GC.heap_info command available even in JCMD itself is from Java 8. Available commands may be different for different processes. To get available commands execute: jcmp <PID> help.

Comment: Yes, I am using Mac. (Can you let me know, how it may make difference). Yes, I think i am using oracle jdk (can you help me know, what all others are available and how can i verify). Process is using jdk1.8.0_172 (verified on multiple java processes). 
I have these 5 extra commands than are documented in my referred link, on jcmd <PID> help -> VM.classloader_stats, GC.rotate_log, GC.finalizer_info, GC.heap_info, VM.dynlibs

Comment: FWIW, `GC.heap_info` is definitely available in OpenJDK 8 also. Maybe only in recent versions? I am using this one: 8u191-b12-2ubuntu0.18.04.1

Comment: Interesting thing is I checked there is `GC.heap_info` in 1.8.0_101-b13 but not in 1.8.0_144-b01.

Answer (score 30):

There is a command line tool with a visual aspect - [jvm-mon](https://github.com/ajermakovics/jvm-mon). It is a JVM monitoring tool for the command line that disaplys:

- heap usage, size and max
- jvm processes
- cpu and GC usage
- top threads

The metrics and charts update while the tool is open.

Sample: [image: jvm-mon]

Comment: Just to note that jvm-mon runs only for Java8

Comment: ^ There's a new version that now also supports Java 11.

Answer (score 20):

Late at party, but a very simple solution is to use the jpsstat.sh script. It provides a simple live **current memory**, **max memory** and **cpu use** details.

- Goto [GitHub project](https://github.com/amarjeetanandsingh/jps_stat) and download the **jpsstat.sh** file
- Right click on **jpsstat.sh** and goto *permissions* tab and make it executable
- Now Run the script using following command **./jpsstat.sh**

Here is the sample output of script -

```
=====  ======  =======  =======  =====
 PID    Name   CurHeap  MaxHeap  %_CPU
=====  ======  =======  =======  =====
2777   Test3      1.26     1.26    5.8
2582   Test1      2.52     2.52    8.3
2562   Test2      2.52     2.52    6.4
```

Comment: does not seem to work out of the box on a SUSE Linux  (line 38: declare: -A: invalid option)

Comment: sounds like you get error in associative array declaration which need bash >= 4. Also another problem may be due to running the script as "sh jpsstat.sh" . If so, try to run the script as "./jpsstat.sh".

Comment: Thanks! Simple and just amazing tool for fast troubleshooting. Must have!

Comment: @amarjeetAnand, what is the default units of currHead and maxHeap? Is there any way to get these units in mb or user defined unit?

Answer (score 14):

In my case I needed to check the flags inside a docker container which didn't had most of the basic utilities (ps, pstree...)

Using `jps` I got the PID of the JVM running (in my case 1) and then with `jcmd 1 VM.flags` I got the flags from the running JVM.

It depends on what commands you have available, but this might help someone. :)

Answer (score 10):

Any approach should give you roughly same number. It is always a good idea to allocate the heap using `-X..m` `-X..x` for all generations. You can then guarantee and also do ps to see what parameters were passed and hence being used.

For actual memory usages, you can roughly compare VIRT (allocated and shared) and RES (actual used) compare against the jstat values as well:

For Java 8, see [jstat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/jstat.html) for these values actually mean. Assuming you run a simple class with no mmap or file processing.

```
$ jstat -gccapacity 32277
 NGCMN    NGCMX     NGC     S0C   S1C       EC      OGCMN      OGCMX       OGC         OC       MCMN     MCMX      MC     CCSMN    CCSMX     CCSC    YGC    FGC
215040.0 3433472.0  73728.0  512.0  512.0  67072.0   430080.0  6867968.0   392704.0   392704.0      0.0 1083392.0  39680.0      0.0 1048576.0   4864.0   7225     2
```

```
$ jstat -gcutil 32277
  S0     S1     E      O      M     CCS    YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT
  6.25   0.00   7.96  18.21  98.01  95.29   7228   30.859     2    0.173   31.032
```

**Max**:

```
     NGCMX + S0C + S1C + EC    + OGCMX   + MCMX    + CCSMX
   3433472 + 512 + 512 + 67072 + 6867968 + 1083392 + 1048576 = 12 GB
```

(roughly close and below to VIRT memory)

**Max(Min, Used):**

```
215040 + 512 + 512 + 67072 + 430080  + 39680    +  4864  = ~ 1GB
```

(roughly close to RES memory)

"Don't quote me on this" but VIRT mem is roughly close to or more than Max memory allocated but as long as **memory being used** is free/available in physical memory, JVM does not throw memory exception. In fact, max memory is not even checked against physical memory on JVM startup even with swap off on OS. A better explanation of what Virtual memory really used by a Java process is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561245/virtual-memory-usage-from-java-under-linux-too-much-memory-used).

Answer (score 6):

In terms of Java heap size, in Linux, you can use

```
ps aux | grep java
```

or

```
ps -ef | grep java
```

and look for -Xms, -Xmx to find out the initial and maximum heap size specified.

However, if -Xms or -Xmx is absent for the Java process you are interested in, it means your Java process is using the default heap sizes. You can use the following command to find out the default sizes.

```
java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep HeapSize
```

or a particular jvm, for example,

```
/path/to/jdk1.8.0_102/bin/java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep HeapSize
```

and look for InitialHeapSize and MaxHeapSize, which is in bytes.

Answer (score 5):

First get the process id, the first number from the process listed, from one of the following: (or just use `ps aux | grep java`, if you prefer that)

```
jps -lvm
```

Then use the process ID here:

```
jmap -heap $MY_PID 2>/dev/null | sed -ne '/Heap Configuration/,$p';
jmap -permstat $MY_PID
```

Answer (score 5):

*There is no such tool till now to print the heap memory in the format as you requested*
**The Only and only way to print is to write a java program with the help of Runtime Class**,

```
public class TestMemory {

public static void main(String [] args) {

    int MB = 1024*1024;

    //Getting the runtime reference from system
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();

    //Print used memory
    System.out.println("Used Memory:" 
        + (runtime.totalMemory() - runtime.freeMemory()) / MB);

    //Print free memory
    System.out.println("Free Memory:" 
        + runtime.freeMemory() / mb);

    //Print total available memory
    System.out.println("Total Memory:" + runtime.totalMemory() / MB);

    //Print Maximum available memory
    System.out.println("Max Memory:" + runtime.maxMemory() / MB);
}
```

}

reference:https://viralpatel.net/blogs/getting-jvm-heap-size-used-memory-total-memory-using-java-runtime/

Answer (score 5):

Find the process id of your webapp/java process from top.
Use jmap heap  to get the heap allocation. I tested this on AWS-Ec2 for elastic beanstalk

You can see in image below 3GB max heap for the application

[image]

Comment: Perfect answer to the original question, which isn't to just display the max allocated heap size, but also the currently used heap. Not shown on the screenshot, but the jmap heap command displays free and used space in absolute and percentage values.
You may have to use jhsdb rather than jmap directly : jhsdb jmap --heap --pid <your PID>

Answer (score 2):

If using jrockit try the jrcmd command line tool. For example:

```
$ jrcmd 5127 print_memusage
5127:
Total mapped                  1074596KB           (reserved=3728KB)
-              Java heap       786432KB           (reserved=0KB)
-              GC tables        26316KB          
-          Thread stacks        13452KB           (#threads=34)
-          Compiled code         9856KB           (used=9761KB)
-               Internal          840KB          
-                     OS        15036KB          
-                  Other       146632KB          
-        Java class data        75008KB           (malloced=74861KB #103221 in 18709 classes)
- Native memory tracking         1024KB           (malloced=102KB #8)
```

For more commands, like heap_diagnostics, use "jrcmd  help" to list them.

https://blogs.oracle.com/jrockit/entry/why_is_my_jvm_process_larger_t

Answer (score 2):

Using `top` command is the simplest way to check memory usage of the program. `RES` column shows the real physical memory that is occupied by a process.

For my case, I had a 10g file read in java and each time I got outOfMemory exception. This happened when the value in the `RES` column reached to the value set in `-Xmx` option. Then by increasing the memory using `-Xmx` option everything went fine.

Comment: top command is showing how much OS is given to the JVM. this guys is asking how we can see heap space usage inside JVM. JVM is using 10g does not mean the real heap space is full of 10g data, because jvm almost never return memory back to OS from heap until you kill the process.

Answer (score 1):

```
jstat -gccapacity javapid  (ex. stat -gccapacity 28745)
jstat -gccapacity javapid gaps frames (ex.  stat -gccapacity 28745 550 10 )
```

Sample O/P of above command

```
NGCMN    NGCMX     NGC     S0C  
87040.0 1397760.0 1327616.0 107520.0 

NGCMN   Minimum new generation capacity (KB).
NGCMX   Maximum new generation capacity (KB).
NGC Current new generation capacity (KB).
```

Get more details about this at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jstat.html

Answer (score 0):

I think jmap is deprecated or something. I used the following command to monitor the heap of a running java app. As in the answers obtain the `PID` from `PS -aux` (or using other method) and use the command

```
jhsdb jmap --heap --pid <PID>
```

You can observe the following details;
[image]

Comment: This works for me. But the MaxHeapSize is always 4GB for me, even I set -Xmx2G. How come ?