# jcmd : where can I find complementary information

Tags: java, jvm

**jcmd** is a promising tool regrouping utilities of jmap, jsp, etc...
You can find [introduction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr006.html) and [man page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jcmd.html) but still it's very light.

On the web, I found apparently existing commands like **GC.heap_info**, that I've never been able to use for my tests.

Some of these commands need special flags. `-XX:NativeMemoryTracking=detail` will give you `VM.native_memory` command, for instance.

But for some others it's not clear how to *activate* them or if it depends of the jdk version, etc..
I can't even find an exhaustive list of existing command.

Any info?

---

*Edit*
Thx to [@apangin response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41893371/2072419), I've started to compute a short summary of available commands by jvm version.

Disclaimer : it comes from code teardown only, not real test

### jdk8

- help
- VM.uptime [options]
- VM.flags [options]
- VM.system_properties
- VM.command_line
- VM.version
- VM.native_memory [options]
- VM.check_commercial_features
- VM.unlock_commercial_features
- Thread.print [options]
- GC.run
- GC.run_finalization
- GC.rotate_log
- GC.class_stats [options]
- GC.class_histogram [options]
- GC.heap_dump [options]
- ManagementAgent.start_local
- ManagementAgent.start [options]
- ManagementAgent.stopJFR.start [options]
- JFR.stop [options]
- JFR.dump [options]
- JFR.check [options]

### jdk9

**only the additional**

- VM.set_flag [options]
- VM.info
- VM.class_hierarchy [options]
- VM.dynlibs
- VM.print_touched_methods
- JVMTI.data_dump
- JVMTI.agent_load [options]
- GC.finalizer_info
- GC.heap_info
- ManagementAgent.status
- ManagementAgent.stop
- Compiler.queue
- Compiler.codelist
- Compiler.codecache
- Compiler.directives_print
- Compiler.directives_remove
- Compiler.directives_add [options]
- Compiler.directives_clear

Comment: The man page has now been updated in the latest releases: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/specs/man/jcmd.html.

Answer (score 9):

Basing on [@EricWang's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41891127/jcmd-where-can-i-find-complementary-information/41891519#41891519), [HotSpot diagnostic command sources](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/567e410935e5/src/share/vm/services/diagnosticCommand.hpp) and the personal experience, I've created the full list of `jcmd` commands available in JDK 8u121 with the additional details about requirements etc.

---

#### help [options] [<command name>]

For more information about a specific command use `help <command>`. With no argument this will show a list of available commands. `help -all` will show help for all commands.

- Impact: Low

```
Arguments:
    command name : [optional] The name of the command for which we want help (STRING, no default value)

Options: (options must be specified using the <key> or <key>=<value> syntax)
    -all : [optional] Show help for all commands (BOOLEAN, false)
```

#### VM.uptime [options]

Print VM uptime.

- Impact: Low

```
Options: (options must be specified using the <key> or <key>=<value> syntax)
    -date : [optional] Add a prefix with current date (BOOLEAN, false)
```

#### VM.flags [options]

Print VM flag options and their current values.

- Impact: Low

```
Options: (options must be specified using the <key> or <key>=<value> syntax)
    -all : [optional] Print all flags supported by the VM (BOOLEAN, false)
```

#### VM.system_properties

Print system properties.

- Impact: Low

#### VM.command_line

Print the command line used to start this VM instance.

- Impact: Low

#### VM.version

Print JVM version information.

- Impact: Low

#### VM.native_memory [options]

Print native memory usage.

- Impact: Medium
- Requires: `-XX:NativeMemoryTracking=[summary|detail]`

```
Options: (options must be specified using the <key> or <key>=<value> syntax)
    summary : [optional] request runtime to report current memory summary, which includes total reserved and committed memory, along with memory usage summary by each subsytem. (BOOLEAN, false)
    detail : [optional] request runtime to report memory allocation >= 1K by each callsite. (BOOLEAN, false)
    baseline : [optional] request runtime to baseline current memory usage, so it can be compared against in later time. (BOOLEAN, false)
    summary.diff : [optional] request runtime to report memory summary comparison against previous baseline. (BOOLEAN, false)
    detail.diff : [optional] request runtime to report memory detail comparison against previous baseline, which shows the memory allocation activities at different callsites. (BOOLEAN, false)
    shutdown : [optional] request runtime to shutdown itself and free the memory used by runtime. (BOOLEAN, false)
    statistics : [optional] print tracker statistics for tuning purpose. (BOOLEAN, false)
    scale : [optional] Memory usage in which scale, KB, MB or GB (STRING, KB)
```

#### VM.check_commercial_features

Display status of commercial features.

- Impact: Low: No impact

#### VM.unlock_commercial_features

Unlock commercial features.

- Impact: Low: No impact

#### Thread.print [options]

Print all threads with stacktraces.

- Impact: Medium: Depends on the number of threads.

```
Options: (options must be specified using the <key> or <key>=<value> syntax)
    -l : [optional] print java.util.concurrent locks (BOOLEAN, false)
```

#### GC.run

Call java.lang.System.gc().

- Impact: Medium: Depends on Java heap size and content.

#### GC.run_finalization

Call java.lang.System.runFinalization().

- Impact: Medium: Depends on Java content.

#### GC.rotate_log

Force the GC log file to be rotated.

- Impact: Low
- Requires: `-Xloggc:<filename> -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=<num>`

#### GC.class_stats [options] [<columns>]

Provide statistics about Java class meta data.

- Impact: High: Depends on Java heap size and content.
- Requires: `-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions`

```
Arguments:
    columns : [optional] Comma-separated list of all the columns to show. If not specified, the following columns are shown: InstBytes,KlassBytes,CpAll,annotations,MethodCount,Bytecodes,MethodAll,ROAll,RWAll,Total (STRING, no default value)

Options: (options must be specified using the <key> or <key>=<value> syntax)
    -all : [optional] Show all columns (BOOLEAN, false)
    -csv : [optional] Print in CSV (comma-separated values) format for spreadsheets (BOOLEAN, false)
    -help : [optional] Show meaning of all the columns (BOOLEAN, false)
```

#### GC.class_histogram [options]

Provide statistics about the Java heap usage.

- Impact: High: Depends on Java heap size and content.

```
Options: (options must be specified using the <key> or <key>=<value> syntax)
    -all : [optional] Inspect all objects, including unreachable objects (BOOLEAN, false)
```

#### GC.heap_dump [options] <filename>

Generate a HPROF format dump of the Java heap.

- Impact: High: Depends on Java heap size and content. Request a full GC unless the `-all` option is specified.

```
Arguments:
    filename : Name of the dump file (STRING, no default value)

Options: (options must be specified using the <key> or <key>=<value> syntax)
    -all : [optional] Dump all objects, including unreachable objects (BOOLEAN, false)
```

#### ManagementAgent.start_local

Start local management agent.

- Impact: Low: No impact

#### ManagementAgent.start [options]

Start remote management agent.

- Impact: Low: No impact

```
Options: (options must be specified using the <key> or <key>=<value> syntax)
    config.file : [optional] set com.sun.management.config.file (STRING, no default value)
    jmxremote.host : [optional] set com.sun.management.jmxremote.host (STRING, no default value)
    jmxremote.port : [optional] set com.sun.management.jmxremote.port (STRING, no default value)
    jmxremote.rmi.port : [optional] set com.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port (STRING, no default value)
    jmxremote.ssl : [optional] set com.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl (STRING, no default value)
    jmxremote.registry.ssl : [optional] set com.sun.management.jmxremote.registry.ssl (STRING, no default value)
    jmxremote.authenticate : [optional] set com.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate (STRING, no default value)
    jmxremote.password.file : [optional] set com.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file (STRING, no default value)
    jmxremote.access.file : [optional] set com.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file (STRING, no default value)
    jmxremote.login.config : [optional] set com.sun.management.jmxremote.login.config (STRING, no default value)
    jmxremote.ssl.enabled.cipher.suites : [optional] set com.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl.enabled.cipher.suite (STRING, no default value)
    jmxremote.ssl.enabled.protocols : [optional] set com.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl.enabled.protocols (STRING, no default value)
    jmxremote.ssl.need.client.auth : [optional] set com.sun.management.jmxremote.need.client.auth (STRING, no default value)
    jmxremote.ssl.config.file : [optional] set com.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl_config_file (STRING, no default value)
    jmxremote.autodiscovery : [optional] set com.sun.management.jmxremote.autodiscovery (STRING, no default value)
    jdp.port : [optional] set com.sun.management.jdp.port (INT, no default value)
    jdp.address : [optional] set com.sun.management.jdp.address (STRING, no default value)
    jdp.source_addr : [optional] set com.sun.management.jdp.source_addr (STRING, no default value)
    jdp.ttl : [optional] set com.sun.management.jdp.ttl (INT, no default value)
    jdp.pause : [optional] set com.sun.management.jdp.pause (INT, no default value)
    jdp.name : [optional] set com.sun.management.jdp.name (STRING, no default value)
```

#### ManagementAgent.stop

Stop remote management agent.

- Impact: Low: No impact

#### JFR.start [options]

Starts a new JFR recording

- Impact: Medium: Depending on the settings for a recording, the impact can range from low to high.
- Requires: `-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures`

```
Options: (options must be specified using the <key> or <key>=<value> syntax)
    name : [optional] Name that can be used to identify recording, e.g. "My Recording" (STRING, no default value)
    defaultrecording : [optional] Starts the default recording, can only be combined with settings. (BOOLEAN, false)
    dumponexit : [optional] Dump running recording when JVM shuts down (BOOLEAN, no default value)
    settings : [optional] Settings file(s), e.g. profile or default. See JRE_HOME/lib/jfr (STRING SET, no default value)
    delay : [optional] Delay recording start with (s)econds, (m)inutes), (h)ours), or (d)ays, e.g. 5h. (NANOTIME, 0)
    duration : [optional] Duration of recording in (s)econds, (m)inutes, (h)ours, or (d)ays, e.g. 300s. (NANOTIME, 0)
    filename : [optional] Resulting recording filename, e.g. "C:\Users\user\My Recording.jfr" (STRING, no default value)
    compress : [optional] GZip-compress the resulting recording file (BOOLEAN, false)
    maxage : [optional] Maximum time to keep recorded data (on disk) in (s)econds, (m)inutes, (h)ours, or (d)ays, e.g. 60m, or 0 for no limit (NANOTIME, 0)
    maxsize : [optional] Maximum amount of bytes to keep (on disk) in (k)B, (M)B or (G)B, e.g. 500M, or 0 for no limit (MEMORY SIZE, 0)
```

#### JFR.stop [options]

Stops a JFR recording

- Impact: Low
- Requires: `-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures`

```
Options: (options must be specified using the <key> or <key>=<value> syntax)
    name : [optional] Recording name,.e.g "My Recording" (STRING, no default value)
    recording : [optional] Recording number, see JFR.check for a list of available recordings (JLONG, -1)
    discard : [optional] Skip writing data to previously specified file (if any) (BOOLEAN, false)
    filename : [optional] Copy recording data to file, e.g. "C:\Users\user\My Recording.jfr" (STRING, no default value)
    compress : [optional] GZip-compress "filename" destination (BOOLEAN, false)
```

#### JFR.dump [options]

Copies contents of a JFR recording to file. Either the name or the recording id must be specified.

- Impact: Low
- Requires: `-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures`

```
Options: (options must be specified using the <key> or <key>=<value> syntax)
    name : [optional] Recording name, e.g. "My Recording" (STRING, no default value)
    recording : [optional] Recording number, use JFR.check to list available recordings (JLONG, -1)
    filename :  Copy recording data to file, i.e "C:\Users\user\My Recording.jfr" (STRING, no default value)
    compress : [optional] GZip-compress "filename" destination (BOOLEAN, false)
```

#### JFR.check [options]

Checks running JFR recording(s)

- Impact: Low
- Requires: `-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures`

```
Options: (options must be specified using the <key> or <key>=<value> syntax)
    name : [optional] Recording name, e.g. "My Recording" or omit to see all recordings (STRING, no default value)
    recording : [optional] Recording number, or omit to see all recordings (JLONG, -1)
    verbose : [optional] Print event settings for the recording(s) (BOOLEAN, false)
```

Comment: I suppose it means you are starting here the documentation I can't find elsewhere? ^^

Comment: @Romain Yes, since I haven't seen all this info collected together either.

Comment: I continued your work, in a more concise form, with jdk9
Btw, thank you for helping me to point out that piece of information in hotspot sources!

Answer (score 1):

`jcmd` itself provides such information when applied on a specific Java process, and optionally a specific sub command.

**How to get help:**

- First get java process lists via `jps` or `jcmd -l`, if you don't know the pid of target java process yet, *(e.g I will take java process with pid **8976** as example in subsequent steps).*
- Then apply `help` sub command on a specific java process, e.g `jcmd 8976 help`, it will list available sub commands for the process.
- Then, get help for a specific command on the process, e.g `jcmd 8976 help Thread.print`, it will print help of `Thread.print` sub command.
- Then, execute the specific sub command on the process, e.g `jcmd 8976 Thread.print` or `jcmd 8976 Thread.print | less -N`

By the way, just as you mentioned, following link describes jcmd command briefly: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr006.html

Comment: `jcmd <pid> help -all` will list available commands with a synopsis.