# Intellij build vm option setting: -Djava.library.path=

Tags: java, intellij-idea, build

My project need the vm option to run properly, with this:

-Djava.library.path="C:\your-path\SimpleITK-2.2.1-Java-win64"

if not configured, every run/debug returns this error:

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no SimpleITKJava in java.library.path

and this is the exact error that i get when i build my project and try to execute the jar.
I'm using intellij with windows. How can i "configure the vm option" for build?

Answer (score -1):

If you need to configure vm options in intellij. Run -> Edit configurations -> Modify options ->Add VM Options. There you can configure.  Reference intellij 2023.1 Version.

Refer this if you are looking at runtime, assuming maven is used as build tool.

[Add jvm options to a Spring Boot application started via mvn spring-boot:run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72482376/add-jvm-options-to-a-spring-boot-application-started-via-mvn-spring-bootrun)

Comment: Hi, i already configured the vm option for run/debug. My problem is with the build, intellij appears to build my project ignoring my vm option, that's what i need to fix.

Comment: So Its about not running the application in IntelliJ. Right?. Build tool is maven?  Try this..  $ mvn spring-boot:run -Djava.library.path="C:\your-path\SimpleITK-2.2.1-Java-win64".

Comment: You can try setting PATH in windows. if its needed to run

Comment: https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm                                   Set Env variable for windows

Comment: You can also try adding the option to the Maven runner in the IDE: 'File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Runner -> VM Options'