# how to config intellij 2023.1 java.system.path

Tags: java, intellij-idea, path

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.2 (Community Edition), developing some Maven testcases, calling C++ library via JNI.

Now I hit a problem that IntelliJ always look for the JNI.dll in ReleaseMD folder.
With `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path"));`
I can see it point to    `C:\myCode\JavaTestPrj/../CppLibPrj/x64/ReleaseMD`.

How can I force it to be `C:\myCode\JavaTestPrj/../CppLibPrj/x64/DebugMDd`?

From menu Run -> Edit configurations, I can see current settings are:

```
 Working Directory: $MODULE_WORKING_DIR$
 Environment Variable: path=C:/myCode/CppLibPrj/x64/DebugMDd
```

, these seem correct.

If I click "Modify Options -> Add VM Options" as this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/76475062/826203 suggested,
there are only predefined options such as `-ea`

Comment: Despite -Djava.library.path is not listed in VM options autocompletion popup it still should work. Try to click on `Modify Options -> Add VM Options` and add `-Djava.library.path=some_path`

Comment: @EgorKlepikov thank you! you are right, -Djava.library.path=some_path can be added into the VM options