# compileKotlin step of Intellij plugin build fails on Java heap space in Github Actions

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, github-actions, gradle-plugin, intellij-plugin

I have an Intellij plugin I built using the template https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-intellij-plugin

My action:

```yaml
jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Setup Java
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          distribution: zulu
          java-version: 11
          cache: gradle

      - name: Plugin
        env:
          CI_BUILD_PLUGIN: true
          DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS: "-Xmx5g -Xms5g"
          GRADLE_OPTS: "-Dkotlin.daemon.jvm.options=-Xmx5G"
        run: |
          ./gradlew check
          ./gradlew runPluginVerifier
```

When running `./gradlew check` in Github Actions, I'm getting Java heap space error:

```java
Execution failed for task ':compileKotlin'.
See the complete report at file:///home/runner/work/xxx/plugins/intellij-platform/build/reports/configuration-cache/avgk7hbsu56pccc278todq8le/5a6oh43i8gcje908b7bopoqxi/configuration-cache-report.html
7 actionable tasks: 7 executed
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':detachedConfiguration1'.
   > Failed to transform app.jar to match attributes {artifactType=classpath-entry-snapshot, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for ClasspathEntrySnapshotTransform: /home/runner/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.jetbrains.intellij.idea/ideaIC/2022.3.1/2a2986db4e11c3d378b4d1c8b9fd040cd6d99802/ideaIC-2022.3.1/lib/app.jar.
         > Java heap space
```

As Github runner has 7GB memory, I'm doubting very much its reaching that limit. Moreover, running locally doesn't incur such memory usage.

I tried to set JVM heap as you can see in the action yaml, but it didn't have any effect.

This heap error is only reproduced for build with platform version `2022.3.1`+ , I'm assuming they just go over the default heap limit.

Is there any configuration I'm missing?

Comment: please output this https://stackoverflow.com/q/12797560/367456 _during_ your gradle build and [edit] it into your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a somewhat known problem, starting with `org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm` version `1.8.20`.

You should be able to up the heap in `gradle.properties`, like so: `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4g -Xms1g`.

Alternatively, you can disable [incremental compilation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew1820.html#new-jvm-incremental-compilation-by-default-in-gradle) like so: `kotlin.incremental.useClasspathSnapshot=false`

Either one of the two modifications should fix the problem.

Comment: Seems to be addressed by JB too https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-platform-plugin-template/commit/6e4a928bbe922e9cb584f8f94b7c05d28d7ac65e Thanks!