# Mono GC max-heap-size isn't documented. Is it safe to use in production?

Tags: c#, mono, garbage-collection

I need to set an upper bound to the memory used by Mono.

According to [blogs](http://inorton.wordpress.com/2013/05/11/capping-mono-memory-usage/) it's possible to use the parameter `max-heap-size` to cap the memory usage.
According to experimentations, and [according to the code](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/394591e203151b57178ca15a75b8af9e89df2af1/mono/metadata/sgen-gc.c#L4934), it indeed does what I want.

However, this option [isn't documented](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/394591e203151b57178ca15a75b8af9e89df2af1/man/mono.1).

Therefore: is it safe to rely on this option in production (or does it have drawbacks I don't see, like e.g.: no guarantee to still be available in future version of Mono)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is documented, and here's one way to get the documentation: `export` an invalid `MONO_GC_PARAMS`, start `mono`:

```sh
export MONO_GC_PARAMS=xxx
mono sample.exe
```

and get the help:

```
Warning: In environment variable `MONO_GC_PARAMS': Unknown option `xxx`. - Ignoring.

MONO_GC_PARAMS must be a comma-delimited list of one or more of the following:
  max-heap-size=N (where N is an integer, possibly with a k, m or a g suffix)
  soft-heap-limit=n (where N is an integer, possibly with a k, m or a g suffix)
  nursery-size=N (where N is an integer, possibly with a k, m or a g suffix)
  major=COLLECTOR (where COLLECTOR is `marksweep', `marksweep-conc', `marksweep-par', 'marksweep-fixed' or 'marksweep-fixed-par')
  minor=COLLECTOR (where COLLECTOR is `simple' or `split')
  wbarrier=WBARRIER (where WBARRIER is `remset' or `cardtable')
  stack-mark=MARK-METHOD (where MARK-METHOD is 'precise' or 'conservative')
  [no-]cementing
  evacuation-threshold=P (where P is a percentage, an integer in 0-100)
  (no-)lazy-sweep
 Experimental options:
  save-target-ratio=R (where R must be between 0.10 - 2.00).
  default-allowance-ratio=R (where R must be between 1.00 - 10.00).
```

As you can see `max-heap-size` is listed, and not in the `Experimental Options`. So I'd say it's safe.

Comment: I just figured this doesn't answer the question. Only invalidates it :/

Answer (score 0):

It is documented in the [mono man page](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/man/mono.1#L1191) :

> Sets the maximum size of the heap. The size is specified in bytes and
>   must be a power of two. The suffixes `k',`m' and `g' can be used to
>   specify kilo-, mega- and gigabytes, respectively. The limit is the sum
>   of the nursery, major heap and large object heap. Once the limit is
>   reached the application will receive OutOfMemoryExceptions when trying
>   to allocate. Not the full extent of memory set in max-heap-size could
>   be available to satisfy a single allocation due to internal
>   fragmentation. By default heap limits is disabled and the GC will try
>   to use all available memory.