# Mem usage is different from TOP and JMAP for java application

Tags: java, memory-management, hadoop, profiling

It's a reducer program in a hadoop job.
"top" command tells me that the RES is about 4.0G mem, and the DATA is 4.5G. And the system begins to use SWAP. I run the reducer with -Xmx4g option.

In the same time, I use jmap to see the histogram of the objects

```
 jmap -histo pid
```

And it tells me in total all the things in the heap sum up to 1.3G mem. I repeated this several times and the result is the same. Why is such a big difference between top and jmap, where is the remaining memory?

I use sun java 7 and in my program there's lots of int[] (allocated with new).

Thanks.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/561450/936832 for an explanation