# Q: how to limit usage of virtual memory by cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I deployed multi node with Apache cassandra-2.0.13 version in centos 7.0. I am using heap size-8G and New heap size-2048M . system used as cached 17GB memory.

How can I limit the usage of virtual memory by cassandra.

Comment: Please elaborate your question and show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: I think it is not possible to limit usage of virtual memory in Cassandra but you can try swapoff command which will help you to stop usage of swap portion of virtual memory. this setting is recommended by Cassandra.

Answer (score 0):

Virtual memory use is generally not a problem. It is not to be confused with actual RAM usage. You can find a good description about virtual memory [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/561450/1662877). Please further elaborate if you still think the shown virtual memory value could be a problem.