# How can too much Virtual Memory negatively impact performance?

Tags: performance, memory, memory-management, jvm

In Java, I have heard time and time again that too much memory can impact performance negatively. When I state memory, I am referencing virtual memory. Specifically I hear this more often than not when it comes to `java -xmx`.

I understand assigning too much virtual memory and systems with a low amount of RAM, but other engineers I have talked with have told me that even on higher-powered machines, you still want to ensure `xmx` is not overzealous. Is there a standard calculation everyone uses to determine this information such as on a 16GB machine you only use 1/4 for `xmx`? 1/8th for page file? I ham having a hard time grasping why ***too much memory*** is a bad thing.

I have been searching all over the internet and so far my google-ninja skills have not been sufficient to find a good answer.

I have looked at [Virtual Memory Usage from Java under Linux, too much memory used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561245/virtual-memory-usage-from-java-under-linux-too-much-memory-used) and this does not really appear to answer my question (or I am just slow and need to re-read it a couple of times). I understand that systems will pull a chunk of memory and reserve it for themselves and I understand increasing `xmx` if out of memory errors are appearing.

My understanding is that `xmx` should not just be given a higher memory number (ex. 8096) unless the application requires it. I fail to understand what is so bad about assigning (ex. 8096), even if the application runs fine with (ex. 4096) etc.

Comment: As always, this depends on your implementation, but Java will tend to use all the memory you give it before doing its most expensive kind of garbage collection.  The fewer, larger garbage collections may be more expensive than more smaller collections.  Also, the cache hit ratio might be smaller.

Comment: @eliasah so form reading what you tagged, GC is the reason why everyone states that not to be overzealous when assigned **xmx**?

Comment: GC and Oop = Ordinary object pointers actually.  GC can be very expensive on intense applications.

Comment: @eliasah Thank you for the information. I will look more into both of those tonight when I have additional free-time

Comment: @antlersoft Thank you very much for the information. Greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I suggest also that you take a look for the oracle documentation about this issue. It's very well explained. (I lost the link sorry)

Comment: The GC needs random access to memory assumes all the used heap in main memory.  If you have a portion of memory on disk, this can slow the time to perform a GC by factor of 1000x or more and kill the machine, i.e. prevent anything else happening on the machine.

Comment: Accessing main memory can take 70 nano-seconds cycles, but accessing data swapped to disk can take 8 milli-seconds which is more than 10,000x slower.