# allocate virtual memory space when executing a program

Tags: memory, virtual, allocation

I want to use a program which calculates tunnels and cavities in proteins. This apparently requires more virtual memory than the program is allocated by default, as I get the following error:

"The computations requires more memory than Java Virtual Machine can currently allocate."

I am executing the program over commandline (./caver_analyst) and would now like to give it more virtual memory without crashing my computer...

So my questions are 2:

1) how can I find out how much virtual memory I can allocate without crashing? (from what I understand from here [Virtual Memory Usage from Java under Linux, too much memory used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561245/virtual-memory-usage-from-java-under-linux-too-much-memory-used) is should not matter how much virtual memory I allocate...?)

2) how can I allocate that virtual memory to caver_analyst from the commandline when first starting it (memory needed might change every time I use the program)?