# java heap memory is larger than TOP

Tags: java, heap-memory

My program run with -Xms10240m -Xmx10240m. I use top to check the memory, the size is 3.5g, it is smaller than the xms valuse.
[use top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2llF.png)

However, when I use jmap -heap, I can see the heap size is about 10g.
[use jmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOOr7.png)

What's the reason?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicated by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/561245/virtual-memory-usage-from-java-under-linux-too-much-memory-used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. -Xms option is used for JVM min-heap size definition
2. top shows the real memory(VIRT/RES/SHR) process used

use your example `-Xms10g -Xmx10g`, when jvm start, it will ask op-system allocation  10g memory which will be used for heap. **And op-system will try to allocate the memory for the JVM (show as VIRT), but system did not promise u it will allocate physical memory, it maybe swap ;)**

But u will find the VIRT is still not 10g, that reason is 10g is for **heap** size, a JVM include much more the heap, for example, stack, permgen(hotspot JDK8, openJDK seems has no permgen, fix me if i am wrong), native stack, code, files etc.

And RES is for real physical memory **used**, it includes new objects, method etc, still not only the heap too.

Comment: Thanks for your information, and it's right that the permanent generation has been removed in HotSpot for JDK8.

Comment: Yeah, jdk8+ remove permgen