ps sum of total actual memory usage of all java threads
I am using this to sum all the actual memory usage of java threads, the result is 13TB but the server only has 1.6TB memory. What's wrong? Thanks.
# ps -eLo pid,user,comm,rss | grep java | awk '{sum += $4} END {print sum/1024/1024/1024 " TB"}'
    13.6079 TB

# free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           1.5T        1.5T        4.1G         12G         12G        4.5G
Swap:            0B          0B          0B


RSS value contains also shared stuff. So you are counting same memory several times.
Btw, respectable amount of memory in your server.

Is there any way to obtain the memory used by each thread but not including the portion which is shared?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/561450/1394729
